# circleci fails when using top-level await

Tags: browser, version, circleci, top-level-await

Circleci fails when using the dockerimage: cimg/node:current-browsers when using top-level await in my projects:

> SyntaxError: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function
> (6:0)
> at _temp._raise

But top-level await is now accepted by all browsers:
https://caniuse.com/?search=top%20level%20await

Is there a docker image that works? Or some other solution?

Comment: did you try `cimg/node:18.3.0`?

Comment: I tried using cimg/node:current-browsers. Is there a difference?